# kodi-standalone no possibilty for poweroff and reboot

Tags: systemd, grub2, xbmc

System Debian stretch. I created for kodi-standalone an own target.

```
cat kodi.target


[Unit]
Description=standalone-kodi
Wants=kodi.service
After=basic.target rescue.service rescue.target
Conflicts=rescue.target rescue.service 
AllowIsolate=yes
```

and a kodi.service.

```
cat kodi.service 
[Unit]
Description=Starts instance of Kodi using xinit
Requires=basic.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service sound.target
Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
After=basic.target rescue.service rescue.target



[Service]
User=kodi
Group=kodi
PAMName=login
TTYPath=/dev/tty1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/kodi-standalone -- :0 -nolisten tcp vt7
Restart=on-abort
StandardInput=tty

[Install]
WantedBy=kodi.target
```

Both are in /etc/systemd/system. But I missing the possibility in kodi-standalone to reboot or shutdown the it in the gui. User kodi is createtd. Kodi boots and I can use it.

```
ls -al kodi.target.wants/
insgesamt 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Okt  3 21:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Okt  3 21:29 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Okt  3 21:52 dbus.service -> /lib/systemd/system/dbus.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Okt  3 21:29 kodi.service -> /etc/systemd/system/kodi.service
```

Where is my mistake?

Kodi starts over grub2 with an own entry with kerneloption `systemd.unit=kodi.target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

I create `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/custom-actions.pkla`  with following content

```
[Actions for kodi user]
Identity=unix-user:kodi
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.*;org.freedesktop.login1.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Now user kodi can reboot and poweroff standby and use udisks2.